# onclick event in Slim not working - converting ' to &#x27

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm trying to set up a Google Analytics goal - an event to be recorded whenever someone clicks on a certain link on my site. I'm using the Slim templating language and Rails.

The Javascript snippet I need to insert is:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action']);"
```

The code I have is:

```
= link_to "A Link", link_path, :title => "A Link", :onclick => "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action']);"
```

But clicks on this aren't registering (looking at the console), and the view-source shows this:

```
onclick="_gaq.push([&#x27;_trackEvent&#x27;, &#x27;Category&#x27;, &#x27;Action&#x27;]);"
```

Somehow the `'` is getting converted. How can I stop this? I've tried using a pipe `|` but I don't think you can nest on link_tos.

Thanks for any help! I've searched Google and StackOverflow and couldn't find anything on my own. This is frustrating and I know the fix will be simple!

Comment: Try `:onclick => "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action']);".html_safe` if you are confident the data in that string is indeed safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `html_safe`

```
= link_to "A Link", link_path, :title => "A Link", :onclick => "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action']);".html_safe
```